# Compare a list of tuples to find the most expensive item in a billing list

Tags: haskell, tuples

here is a question from a past exam paper that I am stuck on. Please help.

Given are types for supermarket bills. Each entry of the bill contains the name 
of a product, how many items of this product were bought, and the price of one 
single product.

```
type Product = String
type Count = Float -- type chosen for simple arithmetic
type Price = Float
type Bill = [(Count, Product, Price)]
```

Define a function *mostExpensive* that given a bill will return the product name 
and total cost of the most expensive entry of the bill (considering how 
many items of the product were bought). Assume there is exactly one 
such product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help guys but I used this as my final answer and checked with the compiler, it works :)

```
mostExpensive :: Bill -> (Price, Product)
mostExpensive [] = (0, "No Products in Bill")
mostExpensive a = head (reverse(sort (map getTotal2 a)))
    where getTotal2 :: (Count, Product, Price) -> (Price, Product)
          getTotal2 (a,b,c) = ((a * c), b)
```

Answer (score 6):

In `Data.List`, there's a function called `maximumBy` that is useful here. It takes a function that does the comparison. To write that function, we'll use a function in `Data.Ord` called `comparing`. All we need now is a way to say *what* we want to compare. So if we define:

```
calcPrice (k, _, p) = k*p
```

Then we can get the result using:

```
maximumBy (comparing calcPrice) items
```

Armed with that, I think you can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more newbie approach that does the job too. Probably scores negatively on the elegance rating but is very simple.

**Don't peek below if you're writing your own. I bet it's shorter than this :-)**

You should be able to call each of the component functions in ghci to take it apart.

```
type Product = String
type Count = Float -- type chosen for simple arithmetic
type Price = Float
type Bill = [(Count, Product, Price)]
type LinePrice = (Product, Price)


myBill :: Bill
myBill = [ (4.0, "Bananas", 0.30), (1.0, "Apple", 0.50), (2.0, "Eggs", 0.25) ]

priceList :: Bill -> [LinePrice]
priceList = map (\(ct,prd,prc) -> (prd, ct*prc))

maxItem :: [LinePrice] -> LinePrice
maxItem lst = maxItem_m ("none",0.0) lst

maxItem_m :: LinePrice -> [LinePrice] -> LinePrice
maxItem_m max [] = max
maxItem_m (prd_m,prc_m) ((prd,prc):rest)
    | prc > prc_m = maxItem_m (prd,prc) rest
    | otherwise   = maxItem_m (prd_m,prc_m) rest

main = do
    let mostExpensive = maxItem $ priceList myBill
    print mostExpensive
```